# Multiple jQ.src in Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

This is my current bookmarklet code.

```
if (1 == 1) {
    var jQ = document.createElement('script');
    jQ.type = 'text/javascript';
    jQ.onload=runthis;
    jQ.src = 'http://www.domain.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js';
    document.head.appendChild(jQ);
}
```

I want to call multiple jQ.src. I tried this however it doesn't work on some sites.

This is my current bookmarklet code.

```
if (1 == 1) {
    var jQ = document.createElement('script');
    jQ.type = 'text/javascript';
    jQ.onload=runthis;
    jQ.src = 'http://www.domain.com/jquery.js';
        jQ.src = 'http://www.domain.com/jquery2.js';
    document.head.appendChild(jQ);
}
```

On some sites it works and other it doesn't Any insight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that works on some sites? I think you're just getting lucky and picking up the site's already loaded jQuery.

Anyway, if you want to add two JavaScript files then you'll have to append two script tags:

```
var jQ  = document.createElement('script');
jQ.type = 'text/javascript';
jQ.src  = 'http://www.domain.com/jquery.js';
document.head.appendChild(jQ);

jQ        = document.createElement('script');
jQ.type   = 'text/javascript';
jQ.src    = 'http://www.domain.com/jquery2.js';
jQ.onload = runthis;
document.head.appendChild(jQ);
```

Also note that the `onload` is only on the second one since you presumably need both JavaScript files loaded before `runthis` will work.

If you're loading jQuery, you might want to check if the page has loaded it already:

```
var jQ;
if(typeof window.jQuery != 'function') {
    // jQuery isn't there yet so load it up.
    jQ      = document.createElement('script');
    jQ.type = 'text/javascript';
    jQ.src  = 'http://www.domain.com/jquery.js';
    document.head.appendChild(jQ);
}
jQ        = document.createElement('script');
jQ.type   = 'text/javascript';
jQ.src    = 'http://www.domain.com/jQuery2.js';
jQ.onload = runthis;
document.head.appendChild(jQ);
```

Adding a `jQuery.noConflict()` call might be a good idea too, the page might be using `$` for something else so forcing it to be jQuery could break the page.

Comment: You were right. I was just getting lucky with sites already loading JQuery. Appending two scripts worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!